# simple IC for on-off current detection?

Tags: current, sensor, integrated-circuit

I am trying to identify an IC that can sit in proximity to an appliance power cord (120VAC) and simply detect if current is flowing or not. On-off output is fine; no need to actually measure the current flow.

I thought this would be a trivial exercise, but it seems not so simple. I have seen a number of examples using Arduino, or similar, but this seems like overkill for this application.

**Can someone please point me in the right direction for a simple non-contact integrated circuit that outputs on/off, depending on AC current flow in a nearby conductor?**

I have been looking at current sensors, like [ACS712](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx)). But these seem to need current flowing through, rather than just proximity.

So then I looked at standard Hall effect sensors. I thought a unipolar version would provide an output signal proportional to average current, which should work in my application. But reading the spec sheet on [US5881](http://www.melexis.com/Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs/Hall-Effect-Unipolar-Switches-/US5881-148.aspx) seems to indicate the output depends on polarity of the field. I think this will fluctuate constantly for AC, rather than giving an average current value output.

Comment: Have a look at the cable finder circuits. I forget what they are called - the things that look like a pen which glows when near a live mains cable.

Comment: Is the power cable flat or round? By the way, the US5881 will output a series of pulses if placed near AC current, and picks up both polarities of current. With a simple interface you can still use it, but check out Tom Carpenter's advice as well.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - don't those circuits detect voltage (irrespective of current)?

Comment: @Roberto couldn't remember if they required current to be flowing or not. You may well be right.

Comment: @Sparky256 - the cable is round. Are you asking because this would imply one conductor inside the other? Thanks for the clarification on the US5881- I thought the spec said output would be high or low, depending on the presence of a nearby magnetic field. I did not see anything about pulse output.  Maybe I just need to research that chip more carefully.

Comment: @Roberto. I asked if flat or round cable. To use the US5881 it needs to be close to the black wire in the cable. The US5881 output will pulse at a 120HZ rate because it is picking up both AC polarities. It is an open drain, so it can be filtered into a clean DC drive signal to drive Arduino or Raspberry Pi. Those are just suggestions and not a complete and detailed answer.

Comment: @Roberto: If you're trying to measure current you will have difficulty as the magnetic field created by the current in the live wire will be cancelled by the return current in the neutral wire. You might be able to detect a change if you place a sensor in contact with the cable so that the fields don't quite cancel out. Otherwise you need to split the live and neutral somewhere.

Comment: @Sparky256 You suggested that that sensor would work, but looking at the datasheet I fail to see it doing anything useful for domestic currents. Additionally, it is *unipolar*, so the pulse rate if it did work would be 60 Hz.

Comment: @W5VO. OK. Thx for the info. I did not want to mention to the OP that using a HALL-effect IC would require extracting out the black 'Hot' wire and placing the sensor right up to it. Also, the open drain output would have needed a substantial RC filter to get a clean DC output that the Arduino could use.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to identify an IC that can sit in proximity to an
>   appliance power cord (120VAC) and simply detect if current is flowing
>   or not

Your whole requirement is "hit" by the problem that any current flowing into the load on one wire is also flowing back from the load on the other wire. These two identical currents (passing through identical wires) cause magnetic fields that cancel each other at quite small distances from the load's power cord.

So, the above method is largely unsuitable and unpredictable.

What people actually do is separate live and neutral feeds and measure the magnetic field produced by only one of these wires. Current transformers or hall effect sensors are used. However, from the sound of it this is not an option to you so good luck in finding a magical method.

Comment: thank you for your helpful reply. Do you happen to have an example of a suitable Hall effect sensor might be suitable? I tried with the US5881, but it was not sensitive enough for household current. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/235298/58362

Comment: If you are still going down the path of NOT splitting the appliance cable then I can't recommend anything because there is a basic problem of alignment and misalignment causing flakey results.

Answer (score 2):

Devices do exist for detecting AC current (rather than just AC voltage).

For [example](http://www.extech.com/instruments/product.asp?catid=31&prodid=128)

[image: Extech DVA30]

> - Non-Contact AC Current detection from 200mA to 1000A
> - Current sensor detects current flow through shielded wires, conduit, and metal circuit breaker/junction boxes

I have one of these and it can distinguish between current and no-current  in an appliance cord that contains earth/ground, "neutral" and "live/hot/line" conductors. You often have to be careful about positioning the sensor.

I don't know what sort of sensor it uses though. I'm not willing to destructively teardown mine to find out. :-)