# US5881 Hall Effect sensor not detecting AC field

Tags: arduino, sensor, integrated-circuit, hall-effect, sensitivity

Yesterday I was disappointed to learn [there is no magical IC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234889/simple-ic-for-on-off-current-detection) to measure current flow in a standard appliance cord.

On the advice I received, I went ahead with a [US5881](http://www.melexis.com/Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs/Hall-Effect-Unipolar-Switches-/US5881-148.aspx) Hall effect sensor and split the conductors. I then passed only one of the conductors over the  over the sensor (to avoid cancellation of the magnetic field from having two conductors in close proximity).

I wired it up as shown below. The setup works fine when tested manually with a permanent magnet. But I cannot detect any pulses when attempting to measure against the AC line. I do not have an oscilloscope, so pulses are being measured using interrupts on a digital Arduino input.

(I also tried with a 100nF capacitor on the source voltage and a 4.7nF capacitor on the signal legs, as shown on the datasheet. The result was the same: no pulses when measuring the AC current.)

**Is this just a matter of insufficient sensitivity on the US5881?** From the other thread I linked, I kind of got the impression this chip could measure AC fields with this setup, but maybe not? Or is there something wrong with my approach?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFupap.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried addressing the problem to the person suggesting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your approach right now:

- The sensor is not sensitive enough. Consider the Biot-Savart law \$B=\dfrac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\$, where *I* is the current and *r* is the radius from the center of the wire. For a 120W light bulb at 120V (1 A), and the minimum separation to the center of the wire (optimistically 2 mm), you end up with 0.1mT. Compare that to the trigger threshold of your sensor (25mT *nominal*), and you would need 250A in order for it to trigger.
- The light is off. Without current flowing (even if voltage is present) you will not have any magnetic field to sense.
- The switch is sensitive to magnetic fields in *only one dimension*, and you have picked the wrong one. Again, looking at the datasheet, the field must be going through the front of the package, which would mean that a wire would need to be touching the *top* of the package for any current-induced magnetic field to actuate the sensor

Ideally I'd like to see a capacitor near the sensor, but that's not your problem. That sensor is really just for detecting magnets as a tachometer or an interlock/switch, not for detecting the presence of AC current.

Comment: thanks! The sensitivity calculations are especially enlightening. I should have mentioned the light was off for the photo only (to avoid glare). And I did also try with capacitors (per datasheet, and mentioned in my post), but outcome was the same. I guess I just need to look more closely for a more sensitive chip. (I know there are off-the-shelf current transformers for this, but they seemed expensive... and wouldn't teach me as much!)

Comment: @Roberto You may be hard pressed to get a *digital* Hall effect system functional due to the signal magnitudes, especially if you have a low current device (<1A) under test. I get single-unit current transformers at less than $3.00 at Digikey, so not *that* expensive. You may be able to cobble together an opto-isolator solution as well, or wire in a hall-effect sensor that is designed to be in-line with a current-carrying wire.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with W5VO's answer.

You may be able to improve the situation by using the Hall sensor in an air-gap toroid.

[image: Hall air-gap toroid]

*Figure 1. Hall sensor mounted in toroid air gap. Source [SoftSolder.com](https://softsolder.com/2013/08/08/).*

This will improve the flux density through the sensor. Adding multiple turns of the wire being sensed will further improve the sensitivity in proportion to the number of turns.

Links:

- [Slitting a ferrite toroid](https://softsolder.com/2013/01/21/slitting-a-ferrite-toroid/).

Comment: I hesitated recommending this as i wasn't sure of the availability of gapped toroids like this, or the difficulty of cutting the gap in an existing toroid. Thoughts?

Comment: I saw one good article regarding cutting ferrite toroids some time ago but can't find it. I've added another instead. Are there any suitable tools included in a Dremel kit?